# How to rotate a view using angle and bounds size of a rotated layer in macOS using Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, nsview, cgaffinetransform

I have CALayer that I rotate using **Pan Gesture** and **CGAffineTransform**. Here is how the CALayer rotates:

```
containerView.layer?.addSublayer(caLayer!)
/// Apply rotation
let angleInRadians : CGFloat = CGFloat(angleValue) * (.pi/180)
let rotationAngle = angleInRadians
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
if let oldAngel = caLayer?.affineTransform().rotation {
  if let transform2 = caLayer?.affineTransform().rotated(by: rotationAngle-oldAngel) {
                caLayer?.setAffineTransform(transform2)
   }
}
CATransaction.commit()
```

Now I want to add a NSView on top of this layer with exactly the same size and rotation. I'm trying to do this like this:

```
let view = NSView()
view.frame = caLayer.bounds // Because Frame is different in case of rotation
view.wantsLayer = true
view.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
view.layer?.borderWidth = 1.0
view.frame.center = caLayer.frame.center
view.layer?.setAffineTransform(caLayer.affineTransform()) // Rotate at same angle 
view.layer?.zPosition = caLayer.zPosition+1
containerView.addSubview(view)
```

**View Hierarchy:**
[image]

**3D View**
[image]

[image]

Comment: What does 'addSubview(view)' mean?  Adding view to what?  Where are you writing code?

Comment: @ElTomato adding view in the same View as of CALayer. 
The parent of CALayer and View is the same.

Comment: What happens if you do not rotate view ? You add a sub view to something already rotated, if you rotate you add a rotation and then change view frame

Comment: @PtitXav I've edited the images. Hope this will clear the details. I added subview to containerView that is not rotated.

Comment: I just want to create a copy of CALayer as NSView with exact rotation and size.

Comment: You could save the frame of caLayer before rotation and use it for view creation.

Comment: @PtitXav That's not needed. I'm able to create a view of the exact width and height of the layer. As soon as, I apply the transform of caLayer to NSView, it gets bigger with rotation.